# Kdenlive affine/composite transparent title over multiple tracks

Tags: video, kde-plasma, video-editing

In Kdenlive, I can create a title clip with a transparent background and "affine" it over another track, to get a "lower third" or "title" effect, and that works fine. However, I have to specify a particular track to affine it over. This means that if I am cutting between multiple tracks (for different camera angles) there doesn't seem to be a way of telling the title to affine over whichever track is currently showing, rather than a specific track. What's the best way to do this? A more detailed pictorial description follows:

[image: a detailed description of the problem]

Answer (score 1):

An older question but since I have the exact same scenario editing sports video and a much newer version of kdenlive (22.04) here's an update. I don't think you need to use a composite transform explicitly for transparent titles. Just put them at the top of the timeline and the affine combination will be done automatically onto whatever video track is below the title at any given time. I believe this is governed by an option on the Configuration/Misc page for Preferred track compositing composition = 'auto'.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just cut the "Niamh closeup" track and insert the cuts between the cuts that you made in the front track? This would make for a track without spaces over which you could overlay the scores.